# My GUI script keeps exiting after a while without apparent reason

Tags: autohotkey

I made the code listed at the bottom of this question. It is an attempt to create a battery overlay for a laptop or handheld PC. The battery works, and it displays correctly. It's small, but it works.

My problem, however, is that it just disappears after a seemingly random, and short, amount of time. I attempted to add 'Persistent' and I've added unnecessary hotkeys in an attempt to keep it open to no avail.

I also tried stretching the invisible part of the GUI over the entire screen without success, thinking that having it duck behind the Taskbar occasionally might force it to close arbitrarily -- which didn't seem to be the case.

My best bet so far was to add the 'Show' command to the timer, which ended up helping with screen sizing changes, but the UI still just closes after a while. My attempts to add a MsgBox to the 'update' function also didn't provide any actionable material. Would anybody know why it keeps exiting?

Note: This is for AutoHotkey v2

```
#SingleInstance Force

battery := Gui("+AlwaysOnTop +ToolWindow -Caption -Disabled +E0x20 +LastFound -DPIScale", "AutoHotkey :: BatteryOverlay.ahk > GUI:Battery")
battery.BackColor := "100100"
WinSetTransColor "100100 130", battery.Hwnd
battery.Add("Progress", "x0 y0 w28 h18 background000000", 0)
battery.Add("Progress", "x0 y6 w30 h8 background000000", 0)
battery.Add("Progress", "x1 y1 w26 h16 backgroundFFFFFF", 0)
battery.Add("Progress", "x1 y7 w28 h6 backgroundFFFFFF", 0)
battery.Add("Progress", "x3 y3 w22 h12 background000000", 0)
battery.Add("Progress", "x4 y4 w20 h10 cFFFFFF background000000 vprogress", 0)

update() {
 status := Buffer(3)
 DllCall("GetSystemPowerStatus", "Ptr", status)
 status := NumGet(status, 2, "UChar")
 battery["progress"].Value := status
 battery["progress"].Opt("c" (status < 20 ? "FF5555" : "FFFFFF"))
 battery.Show("x" (A_ScreenWidth - 34) " y" (A_ScreenHeight - 22) " NoActivate")
}

update()
SetTimer update, 60000
```

Comment: There's slight possibility that after a few iterations of the timer (error happens), the GUI is being closed unintentionally. Try to add some error handling - put the code inside of `update()` function in `try - catch` block. `update(){try{ //your code } catch(error) { MsgBox % "Error occurred: " . error}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a crash because of memory corruption. You allocated only 3 bytes for the SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS structure, but allocating all 12 behaves more stable.

Comment: I know very little about the Buffer object, and the AHK documentation doesn't really have a recommended byte amount, Thank you very much; it has stayed open for quite a while now, so that appears to have solved the immediate crashing issue. I do find it odd that the error that AHK says it throws when that happened never came up, even when using a try...catch... block.